# saving all variables as cookies locally (html and javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, variables, cookies, local

My question is that the first time the reset time button is clicked, it starts the timer, from then on, every time it is clicked, it resets thet timer, if closed and opened (the file html file is stored locally) i want it to carry on the timer by saving all the variablesin cookies.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" , charset="UTF-8">
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100&display=swap');
p {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting up from
var countupDate = new Date()
var days, hours, minutes, seconds

function display() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    days + " Days   " + hours + " Hours   " + minutes + " Minutes   " + seconds + " Seconds   "
}

function startInterval() {
  return setInterval(function () {
    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime()

    // Find the distance between now and the count up date
    var distance = now - countupDate

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
    hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60))
    minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))
    seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    display()
  }, 1000)
}

function resetcountupDate() {
  clearInterval(x)
  days = hours = minutes = seconds = 0
  display()
  countupDate = new Date()
  x = startInterval()
}

// Update the count up every 1 second
var x = startInterval()
</script>


<p>
  <input type=button value="Reset time" onclick="resetcountupDate();">
</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Comment: You are overwriting your result at each iteration

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic sorry but i need to the code working such that the first time the reset time button is clicked, it starts the timer, from then on, every time it is clicked, it resets the timer, the cookies bit comes after, I don't want to get into it before the first part of the question is answered mainly because cookies get wierd when i try saving them locally

Comment: @Greedo  sorry but i need to the code working such that the first time the reset time button is clicked, it starts the timer, from then on, every time it is clicked, it resets the timer, the cookies bit comes after, I don't want to get into it before the first part of the question is answered mainly because cookies get wierd when i try saving them locally

Comment: to reset the timer you have to use `clearInterval`, if not you create memory leaks by replicating the setInterval at each call